# Keycloak ABAC based policy enforcer without adding the attribute in token

Tags: javascript, spring-security, authorization, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to set up keycloak based ABAC, Attribute-based access control for my APIs. I was able to set it up creating a javascript based policy which looks for specific user attribute and then grant access, something like

```
var context = $evaluation.getContext();
var identity = context.getIdentity();
var attributes = identity.getAttributes();
var privileges = attributes.containsValue('userAttributeFlag','Y');
if (privileges) {
    $evaluation.grant();
}else{
    $evaluation.deny();
}
```

This was only possible when the attribute, ***userAttributeFlag*** was added as a user attribute mapper for the client, so that the same is added in the access token

[image]

My question is, is it always necessary to add the attribute in the access token for the ABAC javascript policies to work. The problem with adding that to the token is if we have a lot of attributes that will unnecessarily increase the size of the token which we would like to avoid.

In the mapper, there are options to added the attribute to the userInfo, but is it possible to evaluate that through a javascript based policy.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

To me it sounds like you are using Keycloak's ABAC to implement permission-based AC or RBAC. *True ABAC* assumes a (relatively) small set of attributes about the user **and** a set of resource attributes e.g. `user department` and `resource department`. In that case you have a policy that grants or denies access based on those attributes.

For instance an ALFA policy would look like:

```java
namespace example{
   policy example{
      apply firstApplicable
      rule allowSameDepartment{
         permit
         condition user.department == doc.department
      }
   }
}
```

In your case, it seems like your code is doing the check. this forces you to create more user attributes to achieve the granularity. And that leads to token bloat. This is an issue that is common to all token-based / identity-based authorization schemes. It was true of SAML. It's true of JWT.

Comment: Thanks @David Brossard for looking into this. Yes we are trying to achieve permission based AC using ABAC. If that is the case we cannot help but bloat the JWT. I wonder what is the use of the "UserInfo" in the mapper , is there a way where we can use that instead of the token?

Comment: What if you only sent the bare-bones attributes for the user i.e. department, date of birth, role... and used a PDP on the backend with a XACML policy?

Comment: Thanks will look into it. Haven't looked into XACML policies